# How do you deal with different combinations where we have 2 different objects that are repeated

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

"Find the number of ways in which the 9 letters in the word crocodile can be divided into three groups, each containing three letters if the two C's must be in different groups."
I encountered this questions and I have no idea how I would approach this

Comment: Hint: divide roodile into 2,2,3.

Comment: So I found the number of unwanted selections but I'm kinda clueless about how I would find the total number of combinations

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted.  I suggest considering three cases: two Os are placed with one of the Cs, one O is placed with each C, neither O is placed with a C.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your question is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4554095/dividing-letters-of-the-word-crocodile-into-3-groups).