# Dividing letters of the word CROCODILE into 3 groups

Tags: combinatorics

The following question is from an exam paper in Cambridge A-Levels:

"Find the number of ways in which the 9 letters in the word CROCODILE can be divided into three groups, each containing three letters, if the two Cs must be in different groups."

In the given answer a case by case analysis is done:
\begin{align}
&1.\mbox{ Both $O$s in group with a $C$:} & {\displaystyle\binom{5}{2} = 10}\\
&2.\mbox{ Both $O$s in group without a $C$:} &  {\binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{2} =  30}\\
&3.\mbox{ One $O$ in a $C$ group, one not:} & {\binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{2} =  30}\\
&4.\mbox{ One $O$ with each $C$:} & {\frac{\binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{1}}{2!}  =  10}
\end{align}

for a total of 80 ways.

I don't understand why in the second case the expression is
$$\binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{2}$$
and not
$$\frac{\binom{5}{2} \times \binom{3}{2}}{2!}$$
The order of the groups does not matter so the groups with $C$ in them will be counted twice according to my understanding. Is the given answer wrong or am I missing something here?

Comment: I think you are right (so the given answer is wrong).